# Jboss taking long time to start

Tags: jboss, jboss-4.2.x, jboss-4.0.x

I am using jboss-4.0.5.GA for project deployment, but it is hanging at startup by displaying message

```
Trying to install an already registered mbean: jboss.management.local
```

it is showing this for 6 minutes and it takes total 7-8 minutes to start.
If I start server without deploying application, then also it's taking 7 to 8 min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have corrupted the JBoss installation, highly reccomended to use a fresh installation and deploy your application rather than debug this.

Comment: Thank you amitsalyan for answer, I will try.

Comment: did you solve it? I got similar error, and its new installation.Trying to install an already registered mbean: jboss.adminguide:name=DPSessionFactory

Answer (score 0):

I use Jboss 4.2.2 which is taken from a zipped folder. Today I have renamed the existing setup and tried unzipping again and use a fresh copy. This didn't work out as expected and server is in starting mode for several minutes and thrown error in the end. So removed this fresh setup and used the old one and it worked like a gem, though not sure where is the problem here.